# Referencing a React class component within const component of React

Tags: reactjs

I have a class React Component GalleryExample as in the below figure and I am trying to reference the devextreme-react but its throwing me the following error, what am I missing, any help please?

[Error message is this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mu6k4.jpg)

[My component look as below](https://i.stack.imgur.com/twxuu.jpg)

Comment: check the path of the module which you are importing, It is something with path or your node module did not installed correctly

Comment: Add  2 packages devextreme-react and devextreme

Answer (score 0):

Check the path of the module which you are importing, It is something with path or your node module did not installed correctly